# Пунктуация в предложении верна?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и

«О том, как создать гармоничную семью, и правда ли, что скандалы укрепляют брак».
Верна ли запятая перед «и правда ли»?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, запятая там не нужна, так как предложения: ‟как создать гармоничную семью” и ‟правда ли” — относятся к одному главному предложению: ‟О том”.